# numbers having 4 distinct prime factors

Tags: prime-factorization

What are the numbers that have at least four distinct prime factors up to $500$?

The first number is $210$ and the four factors are($2,3,5,7$) next number is $330  \ (2,3,5,11)$. what are the next numbers up to $500$?

Comment: Can't be that many.  Just keep going and you'll find 'em

Comment: You didn't put a lot of thought into this, huh? $390$ and $462$?

Answer (score 2):

In a problem like this, it's really just a matter of searching by hand until you find all combinations. One can limit the search by for instance checking things like

- What's the largest prime possible?
- Must $2$ be included?

and just go from there. Try to be as systematic as you can (going in ascending order might not be the best idea), and remember that $2\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7 = 420$ is also valid. Good luck.

Comment: 2 is repeated twice.Factors should be distinct.

Comment: @gayathri $420$ has at least four distinct prime factors. It has the four distinct prime factors $2, 3, 5$ and $7$. That's how I read the problem statement. However, if it's not valid, you can disregard that one example, and read the rest of my answer.